# Is Browser store cookies from response first or execute javascript on-page load first

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I have a javascript to find whether the browser enables 3rd party cookies or not.

For this I am trying to get cookie using the cookie key which was sent in response, get cookies javascript executing on-page load to find it.

Do all browsers save cookies from response first and then execute javascript next?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post code. Actually you cannot access 3rd party cookies at all. You can set a cookie using a 3rd party server yourself and then you know. yes, document.cookie is available immediately

Comment: Thanks mplungjan, i will visit the help center. 
Yes,I am using 3rd party server myself to set cookie and trying to access in the same.

Comment: Since you cannot access cookies from serverB in a page from serverA - you use a web bug or image from serverB and then you can use cross browser Ajax to interrogate serverB from the page at serverA